# How to create zoomable plot object using flot library in javascript?

Tags: javascript, flot

Here is my code so far. I can see the selection rectangle, but zooming isn't happening.
what have I did wrong?

```
    function Plot(container, data) {
        this.options = {
            lines: {
                    show: true
                },
            points: {
                show: true
            },
            xaxis: {
                tickDecimals: 0,
                tickSize: 1
            },
            selection: { mode: "xy" }
        }
        console.log("script is running")

        this.data = []
        this.container = container;

        this.plot = $.plot(container, this.data, this.options);
        this.url = '/sensor/oscillogram_debug_data/'+110;

        this.container.bind("plotselected", this.zoom);
        this.zoom = function(event, reanges) {
            if (ranges.xaxis.to - ranges.xaxis.from < 0.00001)
                ranges.xaxis.to = ranges.xaxis.from + 0.00001;
            if (ranges.yaxis.to - ranges.yaxis.from < 0.00001)
                ranges.yaxis.to = ranges.yaxis.from + 0.00001;

            this.plot = $.plot(this.container, this.plot.getData(),
                          $.extend(true, {}, this.options, {
                              xaxis: { min: ranges.xaxis.from, max: ranges.xaxis.to },
                              yaxis: { min: ranges.yaxis.from, max: ranges.yaxis.to }
                          }));
        }


    }

    var plot = new Plot($("#output_plot_container"));

    var updateChart = function() {
        $.getJSON(plot.url, function(newdata) {
             for (var f_id in newdata)
                if (newdata.hasOwnProperty(f_id)) {
                    if (f_id='demodulated') {
//                        plot.plot.setData([newdata[f_id]])
//                        plot.plot.setupGrid()
//                        plot.plot.draw()
                    }

                }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A few problems here:

1.) You are binding to this.zoom before it exists, reverse those calls (and note typo in "reanges"):

```
 this.zoom = function(event, ranges) {
 ....
 this.container.bind("plotselected", this.zoom);
```

2.) Your attempt at some sort of OO scoping within `this.zoom` just isn't going to work. Once that function is bound, it doesn't have access to it's parent scope. If you want the `this` to be available in the bind, you can pass it in as [eventData](https://api.jquery.com/bind/#bind-eventType-eventData-handlereventObject):

```
this.container.bind("plotselected", {obj: this}, this.zoom); // and replace the this in this.zoom with obj
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxU7y/).

Comment: I don't know how this possbible, but I'me getting the exception running your code.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getData' of undefined

Comment: @user1685095, running my fiddle?  I tried it again in both Chrome and IE, no errors.  If you are running in your setup make sure it's `obj.plot.getData()`.

Comment: In my setup. Your fiddle is working. What do I have to make sure of?

Comment: In `this.zoom`, in the `$.plot` call, do you have `obj.plot.getData()`, and did you save the intial plot call to `this.plot`?

Comment: Hmm, don't know then.  Is your page public?  Can you post a URL?

Comment: No, It's not public :-(